# various ways of write distributed cache in hadoop

Tags: caching, hadoop, distributed

What all the various ways of writing distributed cache in hadoop ?
Options :

1. `DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/cachefile1"),job.getConfiguration());`
2. `Path[] localFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);`

what all other ways ?

Comment: These are not 2 options. This is one option. The two commands work together. Another way to get files from the mapper/reducer is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291344/hadoop-large-files-in-distributed-cache

Answer (score 0):

Specify files by the -files options when you submit your job.