# Reading files from hdfs vs local directory

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am a beginner in hadoop. I have two doubts

1) how to access files stored in the hdfs? Is it same as using a FileReader in java.io and giving the local path or is it something else?

2) i have created a folder where i have copied the file to be stored in hdfs and the jar file of the mapreduce program. When I run the command in any directory

```
${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop dfs -ls
```

it just shows me all the files in the current dir. So does that mean all the files got added without me explicitly adding it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, it's pretty much the same. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291344/hadoop-large-files-in-distributed-cache) to read files from HDFS.
2. You should keep in mind that HDFS is different than your local file system. With `hadoop dfs` you access the HDFS, not the local file system. So, `hadoop dfs -ls /path/in/HDFS` shows you the contents of the `/path/in/HDFS` directory, not the local one. That's why it's the same, no matter where you run it from.

If you want to "upload" / "download" files to/from HDFS you should use the commads:

`hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /local/path /path/in/HDFS` and

`hadoop dfs -copyToLocal /path/in/HDFS /local/path`, respectively.

Comment: in /path/in/HDFS  can this be any directory or does it have to be a specific path?

Comment: Any path in HDFS. Usually they start with `/user/hduser/`, but that is just a convention.